# object has no method $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a small issue with my angular app (I'm still in the process of learning!), and I have a controller where I am trying to put a $watch statement on a variable.  Here is the applicable snippet of code:

```
    var controllerId = 'header';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId,
    ['$rootScope', 'common', 'routes', 'authorization', header]);

function header($route, config, routes, authorization) {
    var vm = this;

        vm.$watch(function () { return authorization.currentUser.firstName; },
        function (value) {
            vm.userName = value;
        });
}();
```

Where authorization is a custom service that I created. It will update the first name when the user provides it (on another controller).

I'm just not sure what I'm missing (in regards to the $watch statement.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are able to watch an item on scope in a controller it is generally not a good idea to do so, read this [blog post](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html). I would suggest you broadcast an event from a parent scope (and since it looks like a user login event that's likely where you'll want it) and on your controller's scope, you can handle that event being raised.

Raise an event:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', {prop1: 'some data'});
```

And listen for the event broadcase:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, data) {
    var temp = data.prop1;
});
```

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for. Tomorrow when I have a chance I will look into this and mark it as the answer if it is correct.

Comment: Was this solution helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` is a function on the `$scope` ,[See the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

```
function header($scope, $route, config, routes, authorization) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watch(function () { return authorization.currentUser.firstName; },
        function (value) {
            vm.userName = value;
    });
}
```

But you need to consider here that you can't $watch a variable in a service. You can only watch a variable assigned to the $scope.

if you have a variable like this,

```
$scope.userName="test"
```

you can $watch it like this,

```
$scope.$watch('userName',function (){
//do your work here..
});
```